# How to show calendar on top of dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have a calendar in a dialog, but when I select the calendar to enter the date, the calendar is shown behind the dialog, as shown in the image. It should be shown in the dialog.

[image: Example]

Code:

```
<p:dialog style="align-content: center" widgetVar="mostrar" header="Editar Oportunidad" modal="true" showEffect="clip" resizable="false">
    <h:form id="valor">
        <p:panelGrid columns="4">
            <p:outputLabel value="No.Oportunidad" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.idOportunidad}" readonly="true"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Cliente" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.clienteOportunidad.empresaCliente}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Fecha Inicio" />
            <p:calendar/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Fecha Cierre" />
            <p:datePicker value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.fechaFinOportunidad}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo Servicio" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.tipoServicioOportunidad}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Contacto" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.contactoOportunidad}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Tarifa" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.tarifaOportunidad}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Moneda" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.monedaOportunidad}"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="Vendedor" />
            <p:inputText value="#{oportunidadController.oportunidades.oportunidadVendedor.nombresVendedor}"/>
            <p:commandButton update=":clientesTable" value="Actualizar" actionListener="#{oportunidadController.actualizar()}" onclick="PF('mostrar').hide();" ajax="false"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Cerrar" onclick="PF('mostrar').hide();"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Try with `p:datePicker`, `p:calendar` is deprecated. And guessing by the theme you are using, you might want to upgrade your PrimeFaces version.

Comment: I don't know the PrimeFaces version. It looks old. Don't want to spend my time guessing.